# PHP Contact Form doesn't call value in dropdown options

Tags: php, forms, get

I am new to PHP and I have a contact form on my website where the last field is a dropdown menu from which you need to select an option. The form gets returned with all the info except the option selected in the dropdown menu.

My coding:
HTML

```
 <select id="Product Enquiry" name="productenquiry">
  <option value="Brochure Design">Brochure Design</option>
  <option value="Corporate Packages">Corporate Packages</option>
  <option value="Flyer Design">Flyer Design</option>
  <option value="Logo Design">Logo Design</option>
  <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
 </select>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'] ; 
$cellnumber = $_GET['cellnumber'] ; 
$email = $_GET['email'] ; 
$comments = $_GET['comment'] ;
    $product = $_GET['productenquiry'] ;

if (($name=="")||($email=="")) {
    print("<Script>alert('Please complete the name and e-mail details.');window.history.back();</script>") ;
} else {

$content = "<b>Name:</b> " . $name ."   <br><br> <b>Cell Number:</b> " . $cellnumber ."   <br><br><b>E-mail:</b> " . $email . " <br><br> <b>Comments:</b> " . $comments . " <br>    <br> <b>Product:</b> " . $productenquiry . " <br>";
$admin = "info@ceedeecee.co.za" ;

$from = "info@ceedeecee.co.za"; 
$subject = "Please Quote Me!"; 

$html_data = "<HTML><BODY><table width=100% bgcolor=#dddddd cellspacing=1 cellpadding=10 align=center>
        <tr bgcolor=white><td><font size=2 face=verdana><Br><br>".$content."</font></tr></table></BODY></HTML>"; 

$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n" ; 
$headers .= "From: info@ceedeecee.co.za\r\n";
$mail = mail($admin, $subject, $html_data, $headers);


if (!$mail) {

    print("<Script>alert('Unfortunately there has been an error. Please try again in 5 minutes.');window.history.back();</script>") ;


} else {


    print("<Script>alert('Thank-you for your email! We will be in touch with you soon!');window.location='http://www.ceedeecee.co.za/';</script>") ;



}
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: THIS WORKS!

PHP

```
$name = $_GET['name'] ; 
$cellnumber = $_GET['cellnumber'] ; 
$email = $_GET['email'] ; 
$comments = $_GET['comment'] ;
$productenquiry = $_GET['productenquiry'] ;
```

Comment: can you post your full HTML

Comment: @Ramesh, why post why not get?

Comment: Real curious to know what your form method is. `POST`/`GET` or NONE of the above?

Comment: My form method is GET

Comment: @Satya, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I have tried both POST and GET and still have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the case..

you have assigned

```
$product = $_GET['productenquiry'];
```

and used `$productenquiry` in

```
$content = " .....<br> <b>Product:</b> " . $productenquiry //$product . " <br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your form method is get then you can get this value using:

```
$Your_variable = $_GET['productenquiry'] ;
```

and if your form method is `post` then you can get this value using:

```
$Your_variable = $_POST['productenquiry'] ;
```

Comment: My form method is GET

Comment: Then you can use $Your_variable = $_GET['productenquiry']

Answer (score 0):

Try this... with $_REQUEST and make sure your form close before this productenquiry dropdown.

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$cellnumber = $_REQUEST['cellnumber'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comment'] ;
$product = $_REQUEST['productenquiry'] ;

if (($name=="")||($email=="")) {
    print("<Script>alert('Please complete the name and e-mail details.');window.history.back();</script>") ;
} else {

$content = "<b>Name:</b> " . $name ."   <br><br> <b>Cell Number:</b> " . $cellnumber ."   <br><br><b>E-mail:</b> " . $email . " <br><br> <b>Comments:</b> " . $comments . " <br>    <br> <b>Product:</b> " . $productenquiry . " <br>";
$admin = "info@ceedeecee.co.za" ;

$from = "info@ceedeecee.co.za";
$subject = "Please Quote Me!";

$html_data = "<HTML><BODY><table width=100% bgcolor=#dddddd cellspacing=1 cellpadding=10 align=center>
        <tr bgcolor=white><td><font size=2 face=verdana><Br><br>".$content."</font></tr></table></BODY></HTML>";

$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n" ;
$headers .= "From: info@ceedeecee.co.za\r\n";
$mail = mail($admin, $subject, $html_data, $headers);


if (!$mail) {

    print("<Script>alert('Unfortunately there has been an error. Please try again in 5 minutes.');window.history.back();</script>") ;


} else {


    print("<Script>alert('Thank-you for your email! We will be in touch with you soon!');window.location='http://www.ceedeecee.co.za/';</script>") ;



}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, make sure that **select** tag is in **form** tag.
Then, if it's still not work, paste your full html.

Note: You should use **POST** method like this

```
<form action="/your/post/url" method="post">
```

and get request value

```
$_POST['param_key']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below html and php code
There are white spaces problem in your code.

**HTML**

```
<select id="productenquiry" name="productenquiry">
  <option value="Brochure Design">Brochure Design</option>
  <option value="Corporate Packages">Corporate Packages</option>
  <option value="Flyer Design">Flyer Design</option>
  <option value="Logo Design">Logo Design</option>
  <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'] ; 
$cellnumber = $_GET['cellnumber'] ; 
$email = $_GET['email'] ; 
$comments = $_GET['comment'] ;
$product = $_GET['productenquiry'] ;

if (($name=="")||($email=="")) {
    print("<Script>alert('Please complete the name and e-mail details.');window.history.back();</script>") ;
} else {

$content = "<b>Name:</b> " . $name ."   <br><br> <b>Cell Number:</b> " . $cellnumber ."   <br><br><b>E-mail:</b> " . $email . " <br><br> <b>Comments:</b> " . $comments . " <br>    <br> <b>Product:</b> " . $productenquiry . " <br>";
$admin = "info@ceedeecee.co.za" ;

$from = "info@ceedeecee.co.za"; 
$subject = "Please Quote Me!"; 

$html_data = "<HTML><BODY><table width=100% bgcolor=#dddddd cellspacing=1 cellpadding=10 align=center>
        <tr bgcolor=white><td><font size=2 face=verdana><Br><br>".$content."</font></tr></table></BODY></HTML>"; 

$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n" ; 
$headers .= "From: info@ceedeecee.co.za\r\n";
$mail = mail($admin, $subject, $html_data, $headers);


if (!$mail) {

    print("<Script>alert('Unfortunately there has been an error. Please try again in 5 minutes.');window.history.back();</script>") ;


} else {


    print("<Script>alert('Thank-you for your email! We will be in touch with you soon!');window.location='http://www.ceedeecee.co.za/';</script>") ;



}
}
?>
```